# Does the Dwarven Favored Class Bonus for Brawler affect magical items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class, racial-traits

For a Dwarf Brawler, you can select the Favored Class Bonus:

> Brawler: Reduce the hardness of any object made from clay, stone, or metal by 1 whenever the object is struck by the brawler's unarmed strike (minimum 0).

Is there any reason this wouldn't take effect against magical equipment (that is metal, clay, or stone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Any object” means any object. Nothing says it doesn’t work on magical items, so it does.

Do note that magical items often have *vastly* higher Hardness than mundane items, so you’ll need a larger benefit here to really get anywhere with them.

Comment: This answer seems more applicable to another question I asked. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93657/is-the-dwarven-favored-class-bonus-for-brawler-temporary-or-permanent-and-stacka/93662#93662

Comment: @Ifusaso ...I would swear I *was* answering that question. OK, moved this answer there, answered this one here.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if I was missing some obscure function of all magic items that allows them to keep/replenish their own Hardness. I'm going to leave it open for just a little, but I'll accept your answer before too long if nothing like that shows up.

Comment: @Ifusaso Also, just, for your information, the brawler’s a pretty meh class, and even if dead-set on playing one, the +1 HP or +1 skill point is a far better benefit than this. If you were just confused by how it worked, fair enough, but if you were considering taking it, I recommend you don’t.

Comment: It's the same for Monk and Monk(Unchained), I just chose Brawler because they are the most likely to bother with Sunder feats (being more STR oriented and gaining more Feats in general). I was/am considering a high RP character that's only strategy in combat is to disable his opponents' ability to cause harm. I would of course pass that by the GM first. Regardless, the questions are 75% just honest curiosity. Being able to reliably Break/Destroy magic items would be gamechanging in campaigns against humanoids though. Also, imagine against a golem...

Comment: @Ifusaso Sundering an item generally takes longer than killing its wielder. And unless the whole party gets in on it, you aren’t working together: they’re reducing the enemy’s HP, you're reducing the weapon’s HP, and they don’t interact with each other. Until one hits zero, nothing happens, and the damage done to the one that losses the race becomes meaningless once the race finishes. And then there are the many enemies with nothing to sunder. Which includes, by the way, golems. Despite their construction, they are creatures and have no Hardness. Sundering doesn't apply to them.

Comment: As @KRyan says, killing them and taking their stuff is more efficient than breaking their stuff, killing them and not having any stuff to take.

Comment: Right, backward thinking from 3.5. Regardless, I wouldn't be targeting things we would want, necessarily, only equipment we could do without. Anything damage could be repaired later. I could also target different enemies, spreading the control around, and even if it is the same Big Bad, breaking a target's armor makes it easier for my allies to do HP damage, therefore the same goal. Also, items lose some effectiveness when brought to half(?) HP. Finally, items have SIGNIFICANTLY less HP than creatures.

Comment: For instance, a CR 11 Orc Warchief has 132-187 HP plus can be healed but his Greataxe has 30 HP and cannot be repaired on the fly. He can deal 3x 1d12+14 dpr, or I could break it in one full action. Now he has a Mwk handaxe at 1d6+5 and less chance to hit, then just unarmed 1d3+5 nonlethal which provoke.

Comment: Regardless of if I create the character, I think it's safe to say this thread is beyond the scope, and this question is answered.